# Turn off Inherated CSS Style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a plugin on one of my pages and there seems to be a small conflict with bootstrap and the css of the plugin.

Here is an image of the issue:

Are you can see, the two selects are pretty long and they are on two seperate lines. The CSS code from Bootstrap that is causing that is:

```
select {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    width: 220px;
}
```

[image]

When I turn that attribute off in the Firefox Console, it renders it normally.

[image]

How can I go about ignoring the width in the select without messing with the core CSS?

Comment: What's your HTML structure look like? You'll want to create another rule that's more specific than the first that targets only the `<select>`'s inside the calendar popup...

Answer (score 0):

Make an new rule that will override the last one.

```
select {
    width: initial;
}
```

if you want this rule to apply only to that specific select, and not all of them, just give it an id, and use the `width:initial` rule in it's rule set

Comment: More likely is that he'd want that only to apply to a specific _scenario_, in which case he should find a combination of class/element selectors to use that will only apply to the datepicker popup he's using.